# Visual Studio Code Theming - change editor error indicator

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does the Visual Studio Code [Theme Colour Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference) have an entry for the red underscore used by the editor to signify, for example, a syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this was added in VSCode 1.13 (which is currently the [vscode insider build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders)). Try setting `editorError.foreground`

[image]

Here's a preview of some the other error/warning theming options coming in 1.13: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_13.md#theming