# Visual Studio Code Theming - Change CSS Syntax Error Font Color

Tags: syntax-error, themes, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, tmlanguage

In addition to this great Q&A, found at [Visual Studio Code Theming - change editor error indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44325015/8299327), I am curious what setting / scope controls the **font color** during an error output in a CSS file? I'd like to be able to change the default value. Thank you in advance.

[image: image of error font color]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see with the `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` command, it doesn't really seem to have a specific "error scope", just the standard `meta.selector.css` that other selectors also have:

[image]

Depending on what you want to do, that might still be good enough. Selectors without an error appear to have an additional, more specific scope like `entity.name.tag.css` according to which they're colored. So if you change the color of `meta.selector.css`, other selectors are still colored differently (at least with the default theme):

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "meta.selector.css",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#fff"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]